# How to name a component with a string

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with that i can't get my string to be named with a string! here is my code.

```
public class Load {

    int num = 0;    

    public String getstuff(){

        num++;
        String snum = new String("" + num);
        return snum;
    }

    String name = this.getstuff();

    public void AddString(String f, int v){
        String name = this.name;

        String name = new String(f + v);

    }

    public Load(String s){

    }


}
```

Comment: You haven't explained the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `String` constructor.

```
public class Load {

    int num = 0;    

    public String getstuff() {
        num++;
        return "" + num;
    }

    String name = this.getstuff();

    public void AddString(String f, int v){
        this.name = this.name + f + v;
        // Or
        // this.name = f + v;
        // Whichever behavior you want.
    }

    public Load(String s){

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Why? The problem seems to the fact that op isn't assigning the value to an instance field...